# How can I have a ListView with 200 different images?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a ListView with many different images, but my iPhone 6 Plus runs out of memory as I scroll and the images are loaded, then the app simply stops.  Here's an example showing the problem (for brevity I'm using a URL parameter to ensure Flutter treats each URL as a distinct image)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

List<String> imgUrls = List.generate(
    200,
    (i) => 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448227922836-6d05b3f8b663?ixlib'
        '=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60&foo=$i');

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lots of Images',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Scrollbar(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: imgUrls.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Image.network(
                imgUrls[index],
                  )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there some way to tell ListView to free up memory by disposing of images which have been scrolled off the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use it as

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: imgUrls.length,
   itemBuilder: (context,index){
      return Container(
        child: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(imgUrls[index])
        )
     );
   }
)
```

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

try using infinite scroll list view widget
or 3rd party widget - 
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_listview

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that package, but it still crashes even when I replace ListView.builder with InfiniteListView.builder

Comment: Just remove the itemCount parameter from the ListView.builder and it should work.